# What is a good way to make HP bar in ACM library java

Tags: java, acm-java-libraries

I am using ACM library in Java, How can I make a simple HP bar for the game. The health is an integer like 5 4 3 2 1 0

Comment: When asking homework questions, please show your best good faith attempt to solve it and tell what problems you are having to give us a better understanding of your intentions, what you might be doing wrong, and your goal. Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help), and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions. Please also have a look at [How do I ask and answer Homework questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822)

Comment: oh this is my project, not a homework question

Comment: You are still doing this as a project. You are still asking for people to do the project for you. I am now still calling this a homework question, because it is a convenient stereotype that your question falls into.

Answer (score 0):

First, you fill a red rectangle for 0 health on an area. Then, you fill in a green rectangle with area `[boxLocationX, boxLocationY, health, healthBarHeight]`.

For example:

```
//java.awt.Graphics
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(boxLocationX, boxLocationY, healthBarWidth, healthBarHeight);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillRect(boxLocationX, boxLocationY, health, healthBarHeight);
}
```

This paints a red rectangle and then a green rectangle over it.